# Object creation in constructor

Tags: c++, unit-testing, constructor, factory

I somehow read that it is bad style to do object-creation in a constructor ... however, I forgot why it was considered to be bad style (especially when using dependency injection).

Here an example of object-creation in the constructor as pseudo-code:

```
Myclass
{
    Myclass(MyMemberFactory& fac)
    {
        for(Some criteria)
            push_back(fac.createMyMemberType());
    }

    vector<MyMemberType*> getMyMember();
    {
        return myMember_;
    }
    ...

private:
    vector<MyMemberType*> myMember_;
}
```

So you can use unit-testing without problems, because you can mock-away the MyMemberFactory.
If I would move the for-loop in an seperated initialize-method, it would be necesarry to check for double-initialisation, and all getters would need first to ckeck, if initialisation already was done. Here the code, by using a seperate initialisation:

```
Myclass
{
    Myclass() : isInitialized_(false)
    {

    }

    void initialize(MyMemberFactory& fac);
    {
        if(isInitialized_)
            throw "Error: Double-Init is not permitted.";

        for(Some criteria)
            push_back(fac.createMyMemberType());

        isInitialized_ =true;
    }

    vector<MyMemberType*> getMyMember();
    {
        if(isInitialized_)
            throw "Initialize first!";

        return myMember_;
    }
    ...

private:
    vector<MyMemberType*> myMember_;
    bool isInitialized_;
}
```

So do know any reason, why I should use the second approach over the first approach? Or maybe I just had something wrong in mind, and the first approach is perfectly ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first approach is actually fine. It's not that object creation in a constructor is problematic, it's that doing so with a *constructor* is problematic. So

```
Myclass()
{
    MyMemberFactory fac;
    for(Some criteria)
        push_back(fac.createMyMemberType());
}
```

Would be problematic since clients can no longer use a different factory (for testing, for instance).

Comment: Ok, thanks alot ... I just had the restriction in my mind in a too general way.

Answer (score 3):

If the constructor throws an exception, the destructor will not be called, thus you will lose all the memory that you manually allocated.

Comment: It's the same in his second variant, since 'isInitialized_' is only set to true if 'initialize' finished. The second version is not any better than the first. The true fix is (if you have to deal with exceptions!) to not have a vector of raw pointers in the first place.

Comment: @Frerich, yes, the second version is not better. This is just the only _big_ reason I can think of.

Comment: Good point .. actually in the real code I use auto-pointers for the member .. I removed them to simplify the question.

Comment: But that's true of **anything** you do in a constructor, not just constructing an object. In most cases this risk can be avoided by appropriate coding techniques, or, if not, you can write the constructor with a built-in try-catch block so that the constructor itself can handle cleanup after an exception.